# How can i pass structs across files by value

Tags: c++, struct

I’m able to produce a compilable piece of code that will pass structs to functions, however my code just falls apart when i’m trying to use ‘pass by value’.

I’ve looked at how to use the same formatted struct across multiple files, but i’m not sure if it’s any different when passing functions by value?

*Note: this is written in the arduino IDE in C++*

my code for passing by address follows:

**passingStructs.ino**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

myStruct volatile structure1;

void setup() {

}

void loop() {


  structure1.foo = 7;
  structure1.bar = 11;

  int lower = minusData(&structure1);
  int higher = addData(&structure1);
}
```

**a.h**:

```
#include "b.h"

#ifndef __a_h
#define __a_h

//prototype functions
int addData(struct myStruct *structureC);

#endif //__a_h
```

**a.cpp:**

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int addData(struct myStruct *structureC) {

  int x = structureC->foo;
  int y = structureC->bar;

  return (x + y);
}
```

**b.h:**

```
#ifndef __b_h
#define __b_h

//Define structure
typedef struct myStruct {
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

//Prototype functions
int minusData(struct myStruct *structureC);

#endif //__b_h
```

**b.cpp:**

```
#include "b.h"

myStruct structureC;

    int minusData(struct myStruct *structureC) {
      int x = structureC->foo;
      int y = structureC->bar;

      return (x - y);
    }
```

however if i use 
    int higher = addData(structure1);
in the .ino file and

```
int addData(struct myStruct structureC) {

  int x = structureC.foo;
  int y = structureC.bar;

  return (x + y);
}
```

in the a.cpp file with the same prototype in the header file, the compiler rejects the code saying

```
no matching function for call to ‘myStruct::myStruct(volatile myStruct&)’
```

any ideas?

Comment: `__a_h` is an identifier that is reserved to the implementation. By defining it, you condemn your program to have undefined behaviour.

Comment: This question appears to have nothing to do with the C language.

Comment: Does your `a.h` have prototype for by-value overload of `addData`?

Comment: The error message indicates that the compiler is looking for a constructor for the `myStruct` struct which takes a reference to a `myStruct` type object. This code is a bit garbled in the use of `typedef`. It looks like you are trying to write C source code but using .cpp files so the compiler is treating it like C++ and not C.

Comment: @RichardChambers I’ve changed the file to .c instead of .cpp. However i’m still not sure how i can make the use of typedef to be less ‘garbled’ as you say?

Comment: @SergeyA  - I’m not sure, the new prototype is simply: 'int addData(struct myStruct structureC);'

Comment: @user2079303 - What is the typical way to write #ifndef ... etc. for more defined behaviour?

Comment: @Hazza_ob you can pick any name for the include guard except those that are reserved for the implementation (or used by you for something else). Same rules apply as for all other identifiers. Do not use any underscores, except at most one in between words is an easy to remember rule of thumb.

Comment: @user2079303 thanks! but back to the original question, do you know why the compiler is rejecting the code?

Comment: Why do you use volatile?

Comment: @manni66 - thought it was required for using structs across files?

Comment: No, it is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ will generate default constructors and a copy operator for structs and classes.

For your myStruct these implicit functions would be:

```
struct myStruct {

  myStruct() {}                                // <-- implicit default constructor.

  myStruct(const myStruct& other)              // <-- implicit copy contructor
  {
     foo = other.foo;
     bar = other.bar;
  }

  myStruct& operator = (const myStruct& other) // <-- implicit copy operator
  {
     foo = other.foo;
     bar = other.bar;
     return *this;
  }

  int foo;
  int bar;
};
```

Note that the copy constructor and operator expect a `const myStruct&` parameter.  The `volatile` keyword in your definition of `myStruct volatile structure1;` prevents parameter matching.

You'd have to explicitly declare a copy operator and/or constructor that accept a `const volatile myStruct&` to make your code compile.

`volatile` data needs special handling by the compiler's optimizer.  That's why the `volatile` keyword is important here.  You should really consider whether your data really needs this qualifier.  On the Arduino, there is only one case where this keyword is needed, that is when the data is *modified* by an interrupt routine.

Alternatively, you can define functions that accept a volatile reference or pointer to data:

```
struct MyStruct   // I suggest you use this syntax for declarting structures
{                 // So you don't ghave to repeat the struct keyword everywhere.
    myStruct(const myStruct& other)
    {
       foo = other.foo;
       bar = other.bar;
    }
    myStruct(const volatile myStruct& other)
    {
       foo = other.foo;
       bar = other.bar;
    }
    int foo, bar;
};

int addData(volatile const myStruct* structureC) 
{
  return structureC->foo + structureC->bar;
}

int addData(volatile const myStruct& structureC) 
{
  return structureC.foo + structureC.bar;
}

int addDataByCopy(myStruct structureC) 
{
  return structureC.foo + structureC.bar;
}

// ...
volatile myStruct my;
void loop()
{
   my.foo = 1;
   my.bar = 1;
   int x = addData(my);  // by const reference.
   // or
   int y = addData(&my); // by pointer.
   // or
   int z = addDataByCopy(my); // by copy
}
```

Comment: This is really useful! However could you provide an example of how i would then pass the struct to a function in the ‘pass by value’ and ‘pass by address’ format please?